# How can I pass the tfvars from another module?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.11

So here's my setup:
`main.tf`:

```
module "foo" {
  source      = "../../../foo-module"
  name          = "bar"
  foo_nets = "${var.foo_nets}"
}
```

`foo-module/terraform.tfvars`:

```
foo_nets = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

```
➜  terraform plan -var-file=../../foo-module/terraform.tfvars -target=module.foo 
Error: module 'foo': unknown variable referenced: 'foo_nets'; define it with a 'variable' block
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foo-module/terraform.tfvars` doesn't define a variable named `foo_nets`, it only defines a default value for a variable named `foo_nets` if that variable happens to exist. You still have to define the variable somewhere in the terraform files in the `foo-module` folder like this:

```
variable "foo_nets" {
}
```